# PHP inside HTML Comments/Tags

Tags: php, html

Okay so here is my head

```
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title><?php echo $title ?></title>
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $metadescription ?>">
<meta name="author" content="Talk About Film">

</head>
```

and my pages

```
<?php 
$title ="Talk About Film | Trailers | <?php echo the_field('trailer_title'); ?>";
$metadescription= "Watch the latest trailer for <?php echo the_field('trailer_title'); ?>, watch the latest trailers at Talk About Film";
include 'includes/header.php' ?>
```

In the source however the PHP tags show not the content it pulls from the field. i.e

```
 <title>Talk About Film | Trailers | <?php the_field('trailer_title'); ?></title>
```

Not sure if you can use PHP in this way, or if there is a simple fix?

Comment: Try `$title ="Talk About Film | Trailers | " . the_field('trailer_title')`

Comment: You have `<?php ?>` tag into other `<?php ?>` tag.It is not correct.Fix it.

Comment: You can't embed php within php like that. `$meta = "Foo" . get_the_field(..)` is what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
$title ="Talk About Film | Trailers | <?php echo the_field('trailer_title'); ?>";
$metadescription= "Watch the latest trailer for <?php echo the_field('trailer_title'); ?>, watch the latest trailers at Talk About Film";
include 'includes/header.php' ?>
```

should be

```
<?php 
$title ="Talk About Film | Trailers | " . the_field('trailer_title');
$metadescription= "Watch the latest trailer for " . the_field('trailer_title') . ", watch the latest trailers at Talk About Film";
include 'includes/header.php' ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're already inside a `<?php ?>` block when you open another.  Change it to this:

```
<?php 
$title ="Talk About Film | Trailers | ".the_field('trailer_title');
$metadescription= "Watch the latest trailer for ".the_field('trailer_title').", watch the latest trailers at Talk About Film";
include 'includes/header.php' ?>
```